# How to synchronize two signals in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I'm having some trouble calculating the **correlation**.

Basically my problem this:

I have *inputs [10x100]*, 10 **measurements** and 100 **scenarios** of each measurement. 
I would like to calculate the correlation between each measurement, but I don't know how to include the scenarios.

How can I do that? Will I have a different correlation for each scenario?

Comment: I understand correctly that you have 1 matrix with 10 rows and 100 columns and you want to calculate correlation between each pair of rows (45 values total)?

Comment: @HSchmachty thank you.

My attempt:
A = inputs(1,:); % first measure of all scenarios 
B = inputs(2,:); % second measure scenarios
R = corrcoef(A,B) 

But I don't know if it is correct. I mean, Basically I want to understand the relation between each measure. My biggest doubt is the scenarios. Should I do an average of each measure?

Comment: @zlon thank you. My goal is to determine the relation between each measure. I'm lost here. Can you explain me where the 45 pairs come from?

Comment: You ask questions about aim of your study nobody may answer